# wordpress gives "Error establishing a database connection" inVPS server

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I read all answers like my question on stack, but I didn't find what I need.

I have no problems with "wp-config" file. All is working not normally, till i rebooting VPS. Site working normally for 10-15 minutes after reboot. Then again friert.
I got this error from "wp-admin" in my site:

> Error establishing a database connection This either means that the
>   username and password information in your wp-config.php file is
>   incorrect or we can't contact the database server at localhost. This
>   could mean your host's database server is down.
>
> Are you sure you have the correct username and password? Are you sure
>   that you have typed the correct hostname? Are you sure that the
>   database server is running? If you're unsure what these terms mean you
>   should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can
>   always visit the WordPress Support Forums.
>   please who can help?
>   I am ready to answer all questions

Comment: try changing your host with VPS server ip address.

Comment: please explain in details

Comment: try to match Your username password information with the username password in Your db.